# How do I Assign a Name to a Photo Saved in the Photo Library?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am currently working on a project in which I have to save an image to the photo library and assign a name to each captured image.  I know how to save the image, but how do you assign a name to the ones saved in the library?

My code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{   
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
     imgglobal =imageView.image;    


    //for saving image in photo library
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.bounds.size);


    [self.imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage =   UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImage *image1=imageView.image;
    [self imageSavedToPhotosAlbum:image1 didFinishSavingWithError:nil contextInfo:nil];          
} 

- (void)imageSavedToPhotosAlbum:(UIImage *)image  didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo { 
        NSString *message;
        NSString *title;
        if (!error) {
            title = NSLocalizedString(@"SaveSuccessTitle", @"");
            message = NSLocalizedString(@"SaveSuccessMessage", @"");
        } else {
            title = NSLocalizedString(@"SaveFailedTitle", @"");
            message = [error description];
        }
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                              message:message
                                              delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"")
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
```

Comment: Out of common courtesy, please make an effort to word your question clearly and to use correct spelling/grammar/punctuation. A well-written question is going to get you more answers than a badly-written "plz give me code its very urgent".

Comment: I removed that part of the question.

Comment: I cleaned it up. It's a real question now.

Answer (score 2):

The photos in the photo library does not contain any names. And you can't create a folder in the photo library either. If you really need a name to the photos, put it inside `~/Documents` and implement your own chooser.